# Removing black border from material-ui button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

> I'm using the material-ui datepicker and the material-ui buttons. I'm getting a black border when I click on the datepicker icon to select the date or when I click on any of the buttons. How can I get rid of the black border?

[image: Border in datepicker icon]

Comment: Do you use material-ui KeyboardDatePicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try like this.

```
button:focus { outline: none !important;;}
```

Comment: Also I'm maintaining this style sheet called styles.js to maintain all the styling. If I'm adding this styling to that file how should I add it?

Comment: Add this code to that file and import that style file

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by changing the css:

```
button:focus { border: none;}
```